# How to use iframe on pythonanywhere where content is hosted by pythonanywhere

Tags: iframe, pythonanywhere

I'm trying to insert some iframes into http://elksie5000.pythonanywhere.com/portfolio

As a test I've used this as my src=" [https://www.pythonanywhere.com/user/elksie5000/files/home/elksie5000/erect_penis_dashboard.html"](https://www.pythonanywhere.com/user/elksie5000/files/home/elksie5000/erect_penis_dashboard.html%22)

Why do I get refusal to connect as it is part of the same network?

UPDATE: How to I write that into HTML of the page where I want to host which is on pythonanywhere?

```
<httpProtocol> <customHeaders> <add name="X-Frame-Options" value="sameorigin"/> </customHeaders> </httpProtocol>
```

Comment: It looks like you're using a link to a file that will be only visible to you, when you're logged in (you should rather serve the file via your web app or use static files mappings).  Make sure that the file exists, btw.